# Instiki Hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-hosting, wiki

I am attempting to use [Instiki](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/wiki/instiki/show/HomePage) to create a physics wiki.

Unfortunately, I know next to nothing about Ruby and Ruby on Rails, but I nonetheless brazenly followed the [instructions](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/wiki/instiki/show/Hosted+Services) given by the Instiki creator for running it on Dreamhost.  After following the instructions (which seemed to go through fine), when I access the site url, there is a page that informs be that "Ruby on rails application could not be started", and apparently the following error is occurring:

Bundler couldn't find some gems.Did you run `bundle install`?

You can see this for yourself by visiting [Wigner](http://wigner.org/).

I have, in fact, run `bundle install`.  I actually contacted the creator who suggested that not all required gems have been installed, but I feel relatively confident that they have been since when I executed `bundle install`, I saw the required gems install.

Has anyone happened to successfully install Instiki using a hosting provider (Dreamhost or otherwise)?

Any guidance/links to documentation etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This type of thing can often happen when you have your ruby version misconfigured, what do you get when you run `ruby -v` in the terminal.

Comment: @MikeH-R I speculated that might be the issue after I wrote this as well.  The server seems to be running 1.8.7, here is exactly what I get: `1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]`  Incidentally, I vaguely remember that after running bundle install, there was some message about installing `rdoc` or something of that sort if the ruby version was older than 1.9.2, but I think I got an error message involving `map` when I followed the instructions for doing that.  I can try it again if you think that would help.